# How do I pass a variable to a file that I include?

Tags: php, include

I am trying to pass a variable to a included file. I have done something like this:

`$id = $_GET['id'];
 include('myfile.php');`

And the file 'myfile.php' contains a form and a submit button. It's processing page is 'process.php' and in it, I have done:

```
$_id = var_dump($id);
```

`// insert query`

But I did not get the value of the variable, so 0 is inserted into the table.

Is there any other simpler way of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: The way you show is okay and should work. Can you show some more code? Are you sure you are not inside a function with the last bit?

Comment: Maybe I'm a noob, but I don't think you can save var_dump in a variable.. ?

Comment: @Litso well spotted! It would output `$id`s value but do nothing else.

Comment: Are you using `var_dump` to escape a string for a SQL query ... ?

Comment: "It's processing page is 'process.php' and in it, I have done:"  -- Can you elaborate on this more, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions.

Have `myfile.php` declare a function (e.g. myfunction), which you call in the including script.

For example:

```
// main.php
<?php

include('myfile.php');

process_data($_GET['id']);

// myfile.php
<?php

function process_data($id) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE id = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($id);

    // ...
}
```

If you really want to pass the variable as a global, and you're referencing the global in a function or method, be sure to reference it as [`$GLOBALS['varname']`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) or to use [`global $varname`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

```
function process_data() {
    $id = &$GLOBALS['id'];
    // or
    global $id;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for clean code! Using variables across multiple files results in a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass over the value of $id inside your form in myfile.php

example:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $id ?>">
  <!--- rest of your form -->
</form>
```

in your process.php, get the id back as following and do then your query.

```
$form_id = $_POST['id'];
```